# Multiple "Page N of M" in a single VB6 ActiveReport

Tags: vb6, activereports

I have an active report which generates a report of multiple pages. 
I need it to show page N of M multiple times based on a field "COID" 
present in Details section. 
For Eg- if there are 10 pages(2 for COID 1001, 1 for COID 1002 and 7 for COID 1003)
So, I want the pages like "Pages 1 of 2", "Pages 2 of 2", "Pages 1 of 1", "Pages 1 of 7", "Pages 2 of 7".... "Pages 7 of 7".

Please help.

Comment: Which version of Active Reports do you use? I'm usually running the report first-pass in the background just to get the counts per grouping (placing "N of N" instead), then second-pass renders "N of M" text, hoping it will not "spill" on two lines and modify report layout.

Comment: Active Reports Version 1.x.
It's the oldest one. Can you please elaborate your procedure a bit and whether it can be used in this version?

Comment: Place a hidden field on `PageHeader` and bind it to `COID` field. Create a new instance of the report, bind it and collect a map (a VB6 Collection or similar) of Page<->COID using the hidden field. Use this map to count pages per COID and render "N of M" on the report presented to the user.

Comment: Thanks wqw,
I am trying the above method. I want to know how to create multiple instance of the report. I currently have Private Sub ActiveReport_Initialize() and Private Sub ActiveReport_ReportEnd() in the code. 
Being new to VB6 I dont have much idea about it.
Thanks

Comment: Add a public method to the report -- like `Init` -- that binds the report and shows it. Don't call `ActiveReport1.Show` directly. Do this: `Set myReport = New ActiveReport1 : myReport.Init rsData`. In `Init` you can create an instance of itself with `Set myCopy = New ActiveReport1 : myCopy.CalcPages rsData` where `CalcPages` just binds, inits the map, waits for render to finish and returns the collection.

Comment: I am not getting, It do not support Init.
Can you provide me the sample code? or do you want me to provide you the same? I am badly stuck with this issue.

Comment: No, not here. You can find a freelancer to do your job quickly

Answer (score 1):

I have worked only with AR version 3.00 on wards. In these it could be achieved very quickly and easily using a sub report.

I did a quick research on this and found earlier version  [supports sub reports](http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/302/ShowPost.aspx)

How to do this using a sub report follow the article in the link and create a parent and child/sub reports. For parent report data you just run a SQL query group by COID and pass each COID to the sub report. I would have envisage an almost blank parent report with a detail section in that detail section insert a sub report control. Assign your existing report to the sub report control.

Sub report has their own issues as long as we keep the parent and sub report communication simple. And also create only one sub report instance object in the parent report. Use the same instance to pass the parameter from each row in the parent dataset which is COID.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. Run a single report and reset the page numbering on each group and running the report multiple times and merging pages together into one report.

**Resetting Page Number for Each Group**

See [this topic](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/AR2Std/HX_Page_N_of_M_in_the_Group_Header.html) in the ActiveReports for ActiveX/COM [documentation](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/AR2Std/AR2Std_start.htm). It is merely a matter of setting the right properties on the textbox control.

**Merging Reports Together**

In this method you can run the report separately for each COID group (e.g. using a WHERE clause to get the right data). This will get the page numbers the way you want in each COID report. Then you can merge the pages from each of tho together into a single report. So something like the following:

```
For iRpt = 0 to myReports.Count - 1
    rpt = myReports[iRpt]
    For iPage = 0 to rpt.Pages.Count – 1
        mainReport.Pages.Insert(rpt.Pages(iPage))
    Next iPage
Next iRpt
```

Find more information on the [Pages collection here](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/AR2Std/HX_Pages.html).